# Change the behavior of carriage return

Tags: macros, formatting, catcodes, verse

Define an enhance `verse` environment, where stroke Carriage return key once make a `\\`, twice make a `\par`, three times make a `\medskip`, four times and more make a `\bigskip`.

An example would be:

```
\begin{enhanceverse}
The furthest distance in the world
Is not between life and death
But when I stand in front of you
Yet you don't know that I love you


The furthest distance in the world
Is not when I stand in front of you
Yet you can't see my love
But when undoubtedly knowing the love from both

Yet cannot be together




---Anonymous
\end{enhanceverse}
```

which should output a similar appearance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) What is the background of such a question? (Is it a homework?)

Comment: It sounds like the `verbatim` environment might also be of interest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make the carriage return active and use a counter as follows.
Watch out for the `%` used in the definition. They are to mask carriage returns in the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{enhanceverse}{%
    \verse
    \futurelet\next\@enhanceverse
}{%
    \endverse
}

\newcounter{enhanceversecr}

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=\active%
\gdef\@enhanceverse{%
    \catcode`\^^M=\active%
    \let^^M\@enhanceverse@cr%
}%
\gdef\@enhanceverse@cr{%
    \stepcounter{enhanceversecr}%
    \@ifnextchar^^M{}{%
        \ifcase\c@enhanceversecr%
        \or\\%
        \or\par%
        \or\par\medskip%
        \else\par\bigskip%
        \fi%
        \setcounter{enhanceversecr}{0}%
    }%
}%
\endgroup%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enhanceverse}
The furthest distance in the world
Is not between life and death
But when I stand in front of you
Yet you don't know that I love you


The furthest distance in the world
Is not when I stand in front of you
Yet you can't see my love
But when undoubtedly knowing the love from both

Yet cannot be together




---Anonymous
\end{enhanceverse}


\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Missing `%` in the `\ifcase` line? It may be simpler to set `\endlinechar=-1`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Indeed (fixed now). I wonder why I didn't got an error. I wasn't sure about `\endlinechar` while `^^M` is active, so I played it save.

Comment: There's a neater way to avoid worrying about end-of-lines: say `\begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M \lowercase{\endgroup` and do the same definitions (`\gdef` is not necessary, so use `\def`) changing `^^M` into `~`. Remember a closing `}` in place of `\endgroup`. Very neat the `\expandafter` to tokenize the following possible end-of-line, but maybe `\futurelet\next` can be better, as it avoids possible issues with expansion.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, the `\lowercase` trick. It didn't popped into my mind. Funny, it seldom does. About the `\futurelet`: Maybe a dummy `\@ifnextchar` would be better.

Comment: Well, `\@ifnextchar` does almost the same as `\futurelet\next` (but it swallows spaces).

Comment: @egreg `\expandafter\@enhanceverse\noexpand` also works to avoid expansion I think. But I agree that `\futurelet` is a safer approach. (or the crazy `\begingroup\aftergroup\@enhanceverse\futurelet\next\endgroup`). @Martin: actually, swallowing spaces may be bad, here.

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt provides a `lines` environment in which the user line breaks are honored (similar to `<pre>` tags in HTML). FWIW, you can achieve the desired behavior by setting

```
\setuplines[inbetween={\null\blank}]
```

and then using

```
\startlines
 ....
\stoplines
```

This is not exactly same as what you want, if you have three `\r`, you get the same space as two empty lines, and so on. But this will also work if you have spaces on empty lines and so on.